# Update date only in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this row in my database table with a value of  `1/5/2013 5:50:00 PM`, and I want to update only the date part. Time should be same without any change, need to change only the date in this record.

I have tried the update statement but it change the time as well..but I can do a

```
UPDATE table1
SET date = '1/10/2013 5:50:00 PM'
WHERE id =1
```

This not what I'm looking for, different id's have different times, so just need to update the date keeping the time in that record same.

Please give feedback.

Thank you

Comment: Which SQL Server Version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way if you're using SQL Server 2008 or higher

```
UPDATE table1
SET [date] = cast('1/10/2013' as datetime) + cast(cast([date] as time) as datetime)
WHERE id =1
```

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or below, you there's no `time` data type, so you have to do:

```
UPDATE table1
SET [date] = cast('1/10/2013' as datetime) + ([date] - DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [date])))
WHERE id =1
```

Comment: i'm using SQL server 2005

Comment: Updated my answer for 2005.

Comment: okay, let me try that now

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table1
SET date = DATEADD(dd,5,date)-- 5 is the number of days
FROM table1
WHERE id =1
```

Comment: this only apply for adding right? 
sometimes i want to change the date, month and year. how to do that?

Comment: Use `DATEDIFF` to find the difference in number of days and pass that value to the `DATEADD`

Comment: @user3073987: have you even bothered looking at the [SQL Server Books Online documentation for `DATEADD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)??? You could **easily** see that you can do this for days, months, years, seconds, minutes - whatever you like. Learn to find and read the docs!

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but should work. Idea is to extract hours,minutes and seconds from target row and hard code other parts.

```
update table1 set date = DATEADD(second, DATEPART(second, date), DATEADD(minute, DATEPART(minute, date), DATEADD(hour, DATEPART(hour,date), '2013-01-10')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit hackish in appearance, this will do the trick if you ONLY want to change the date part with an arbitary value, and not touch the time part at all:

```
update table1 set date= '06-dec-2013 ' + cast(datepart(HOUR,date) as varchar(2)) + ':' + 
cast(datepart(MINUTE,date) as varchar(2)) + ':' +
cast(DATEPART(SECOND, date) as varchar(2)) + ' ' +
CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, date) < 12 THEN 'AM' ELSE 'PM' END as datetime
where id=1
```

Replace '06-dec-2013' with the date value you want to replace with.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t
(
col1 datetime
)

Insert Into t 
values ('1/5/2013 5:50:00 PM')



declare @newDate datetime

set @newDate = '1/10/2013'

update t
Set col1 = convert(datetime,DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, col1, @newDate), Col1),101)
```

### <kbd>[sql-fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4daaf/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query you want:

```
declare @TargetDate datetime
set @TargetDate = '20131001' --1st October 2013

update table1 set [date] = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,[date],@TargetDate),[date])
where id = 1
```

And here's a complete script to demonstrate it:

```
declare @t table (dt datetime not null)
insert into @t (dt) values
('2001-01-01T10:53:44.993'),('2012-06-18T15:33:33.333')

declare @TargetDate datetime
set @TargetDate = '20131001' --1st October 2013

update @t set dt = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,dt,@TargetDate),dt)

select * from @t
```

Results:

```
dt
-----------------------
2013-10-01 10:53:44.993
2013-10-01 15:33:33.333
```

This works by using `DATEDIFF` to work out how many days different the target date is from each date stored in the table (with appropriate signage) and then adding that difference back onto the date - having the effect of adjusting the date portions of the stored values whilst not affecting the time.